# AsyncStorage with multiple components and Context

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, promise, asyncstorage

I use the AsyncStorage to save the settings of the user.
Here you have my app.js :

```
export default function App() {
  const [currency, setCurrency] = useState(async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@currency')
      console.log('value get', value)
      return value != null ? JSON.parse(value) : true
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Get settings values failed:', e)
    }
  })
}
```

And in the Render method I start with :

```
<SettingsContext.Provider value={{ currency, setCurrency }}>
```

This works.

Now, I have a deep component:

```
export function NavigatorSettings() {
  const { currency, setCurrency } = useContext(SettingsContext)

  // const toggleCurrency = () => setCurrency(previousCurrency => !previousCurrency)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('currency Effect', currency)
  }, [])

  async function toggleCurrency() {
    setCurrency(previousCurrency => !previousCurrency)
    console.log('currency', currency)
    try {
      const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(currency)
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@currency', jsonValue)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Set settings values failed:', e)
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings tab</Text>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>EUR</Text>
        <Switch style={{ margin: 12 }} onChange={toggleCurrency} value={currency} />
        <Text>USD</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

The useEffect display this: currency Effect {"_h": 0, "_i": 1, "_j": false, "_k": null}

If I select the Switch, then it's "work" (Looks like nothing are set in the AsyncStorage.setItem, but I tried to understand the console.log first).

I guess it's about Promise, but I haven't idea to get this right.

Thanks for your help.

Google and read the doc.

Comment: An `async` function always returns a promise. `useState(async () => ...)` causes the state hook to store the promise that is return by the function. `useState` won't unwrap the promise.